# Value of an assignment in awk, ternary operator parsing in awk

Tags: awk

I new to awk and playing around with it. When trying to use the ternary operator, at some point I wanted to execute two operations upon true condition, and as I couldn't find the syntax to do so I tried to smuggle one of the two operations inside the condition to take advantage of the lazy evaluation.

I have an input file as follow:

```
file.csv

A,B,C,D
1,,,
2,,,
3,,,
4,,,
5,,,
6,,,
7,,,
8,,,
```

And I'd like, for the sake of the exercise, to put assign B and C to 0 if A is less than 5 ; C to 1 if A is 5 or more.
I guess the ternary operator is a terrible way to do this but this is not my point.

The question is: why does the following line outputs that? How does awk parse this expression ?

`awk '(FNR!=1){$1<5 && $3=0 ? $2=0 : $2=1}{print $0}' FS=, OFS=, file.csv`

Output:

```
1,1,1,
2,1,1,
3,1,1,
4,1,1,
5,,,
6,,,
7,,,
8,,,
```

I was expecting the `$3=0` expression to be executed and evaluated to `true`, and being skipped when the first part of the condition (`$1<5`) is false.

Expected result:

```
1,0,0,
2,0,0,
3,0,0,
4,0,0,
5,1,,
6,1,,
7,1,,
8,1,,
```

Extra question: can I actually use the ternary operator and have in it several instructions executed depending on the condition value ? Is it only a bad practice or actually impossible ?

Comment: regarding your extra question, *some* statements could be done this way, but not all of them. you can even do multiple `getline`s within one single scenario of the ternary operator - just wrap them by dummy `substr( )`s that you've explicitly set output length to zero

Comment: so while this example isn't a ternary, it demos how the `substr()/sprintf()` wrapper works - this function goes to the shell, gets micro-second timestamps from `gnu-date`, as a single through `return statement` for the function : `function usectime(_,__,___) { return sprintf("%.*s%*s", (___=RS)*(RS="\n"), (_=" gdate +\47%s%6N\47 ")|getline __, close(_)^(RS=___), __) }`

Answer (score 5):

***1st solution:*** You should have like this code, written and tested with your shown samples and attempts. I have used ternary operators to check if value of 1st field is lesser than 5 or not and based on that setting values for 2nd and 3rd fields here.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  $2=($1<5?0:$1)
  $3=($1<5?0:$3)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(Generic approach):*** If you have to pass N number of fields to be checked in program then better create a function and do the checks and assignment there, using again ternary operators here for computation.

***Where:***

- `threshold` is an `awk` variable which is assigned to `5` value by which you want to do comparison fir 1st field.
- `fieldCompare` is again an `awk` variable which contains `1` in this case since we want to compare 1st field value to 5 here.
- `checkValue` is function where field numbers(eg: `2` and `3` in this case) are being passed with comma separated values to be checked in a single shot within function.

```bash
awk -v threshold="5" -v fieldCompare="1" '
function checkValue(fields){
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    fieldNum = arr[i]
    $fieldNum = ($fieldCompare<threshold?0:$fieldNum)
  }
}
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
checkValue("2,3")
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

If I look at the expected outcome, the 2nd field should be one.

Setting field 2 and 3 to zero if field 1 is smaller than five, else set field 2 to one.

The one at the end `}1` evaluates to true and will print the whole line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}(FNR!=1){($1 < 5) ? $2=$3=0 : $2=1}1' file.csv
```

Output

```
A,B,C,D
1,0,0,
2,0,0,
3,0,0,
4,0,0,
5,1,,
6,1,,
7,1,,
8,1,,
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write cryptic code, this is one way to do it. You don't even need the ternary operator.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR>1  {$2=$1>=5 || $3=0 }1' file

A,B,C,D
1,0,0,
2,0,0,
3,0,0,
4,0,0,
5,1,,
6,1,,
7,1,,
8,1,,
```

Comment: or perhaps even  `awk 'NR == 1 || $2 = 5 <= $1 || ($3 = 0)_' FS=, OFS=,`

Answer (score 3):

> I was expecting the $3=0 expression to be executed and evaluated to true

The result of an assignment is the value assigned. [Zero is false](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html).

> ... and being skipped when the first part of the condition ($1<5) is false.

Since `&&` has a [higher precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Precedence.html) than `?:`, and `?:` has a higher precedence than `=`, awk is doing this:

```
$1<5 && ($3 = (0 ? $2=0 : $2=1))
```

When $1 < 5, if 0 is true (it is not) then assign $3 the result of  $2 = 0, **else assign $3 the result of $2 = 1**.

When $1 >= 5, do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

tested and confirmed working on `mawk-1`, `mawk-2`, `gawk`, and `nawk` :

> ```
> only difference being order of precedence at 3rd section
> ```

```
{g,n}awk 'BEGIN { _+=_^=FS=OFS="," } NR<_ || ($_=_^_<+$!_) || $(_--)=!++_ ""'

      or

    mawk 'BEGIN { _+=_^=FS=OFS="," } NR<_ || ($_=_^_<+$!_) || $++_ = !--_ ""'
```

|

```
A,B,C,D
1,0,0,
2,0,0,
3,0,0,
4,0,0,
5,1,,
6,1,,
7,1,,
8,1,,
```

concating with empty string (`""`) at the tail ensures print out for a zero-value assignment